# How do I add an event listener for checking radio buttons using regular javascript?

Tags: javascript

As you can see below in the snippet if two buttons are checked an error is put in. I want to do this in real time without me having to do "checked = "checked". I'm not sure what to do with event listener to achieve this

```js
function check(form) {
  let count = 0
  const boxes = form.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    if(box.checked === true) {
      count += 1
    }
  })
  if(count > 1) {
    const error = form.querySelector("span[class=error]")
    error.innerHTML = "don't check more than 1"
  }
  


}
check(document.querySelector("#form1"))
```

```html
<form id="form1">

            <label>A
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">

            </label> <br />


            <label>B
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            </label> <br />
            
             <label>C
                <input type="checkbox">
            </label> <br />
            
            <span class="error"> </span>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple use `querySelectorAll` method with `foreach` function wrap your `change` `addEventListener` inside `forEeach`.

Show error if checkbox is checked more then once. Else hide the error.

Run snippet below.

```js
//Get all checkbox
const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")

//Error
const error = document.querySelector(".error")

//Count
let count = 0

//Check all checkbox
checkbox.forEach(box => { 
  //Add event listener
  box.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    //Increase count on checked
    if (event.target.checked) {
      count += 1
    } else {
      count -= 1
    }
    //Show error on count >= 1 / else nothing
    if (count >= 1) {
      error.textContent = "don't check more than 1"
    } else {
      error.textContent = ''
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="form1">

  <label>A
                <input type="checkbox" >
            </label> <br />

  <label>B
                <input type="checkbox"  >
            </label> <br />

  <label>C
                <input type="checkbox" >
            </label> <br />

  <span class="error"> </span>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change event.

```
let count = 0
  const boxes = form.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
  boxes.forEach(box => {
      box.addEventListener("change", function(e){
          if(box.checked) count++;
           else count--;
           if(count > 1) {
            const error = form.querySelector("span[class=error]")
            error.innerHTML = "don't check more than 1"
           }
      });
  });
```